# Angular 7 / TypeScript: pegar valor de dentro de uma função onload (upload de arquivos, pegar o conteúdo de um arquivo)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file-upload, assincronismo

Eu tenho o código abaixo onde eu faço o upload de um arquivo e quero obter o seu conteúdo em uma variável.

Para isso utilizo a função `onload` que me obtém o `result`, que é o conteúdo do arquivo.

Mas a variável dá `undefined` fora do `onload`, como fazer esse resultado poder ser utilizado fora dessa função?

```js
if(event.target.files.length > 0) {
    let fileContent;
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
        fileContent = fileReader.result;
        console.log(fileContent); //aqui eu tenho o conteúdo completo do arquivo
    };

    fileReader.readAsText(file);

    console.log(fileContent); //aqui é undefined
    }
  }
```

Comment: Não é passado nenhum parâmetro no `fileResult`.Você já tentou printar o resultado do file ?
Creio que o resultado do arquivo esteja nessa variável.

Comment: Ele só vai existir dentro do onload pois é a função que é chamada quando ele termina de receber o arquivo

Comment: @VictorHenrique não entendi qual seria o fileResult

Comment: @EduardoVargas sim, preciso de uma forma de fazer essa informação persistir a isso e aparecer fora dessa função.

Comment: Voce pode setar o valor pra uma propriedade do seu componente. Mas ele só vai estar com o valor quando função rodar pois é asincrono.

Comment: Pensa que tem um tempo até o arquivo ser enviado.

Comment: @EduardoVargas, certo, poderia me mostrar um exemplo de como retornar esse resultado para o que estou buscando?

Comment: O comportamente do código que você compartilhou é o esperado, já que se trata de uma API assíncrona. O que você quer fazer com o resultado depois? Será mais fácil de te ajudar se entendermos o contexto.

Comment: @LeonardoLima quero salvar esse valor numa variável para depois montar um objeto e salvar via api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema que eu estava tendo era que o conteúdo da função onload acontecia depois do resto do código, deixando esses dados como null.

Solução, refazer a função

```
async uploadFile(event) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];

    reader.onload = ((file: any) => {
      return (e: Event) => {
        this.document.description = e.srcElement.result; 
        //tenho um objeto document, e adiciono o conteúdo do arquivo encontrado pelo onload


        this.myFunction(this.document);
        //pulo do gato: chamar a continuidade do script dentro do onload, pois o conteúdo do result só existe dentro dessa função, por isso, passe esse conteúdo para o objeto e o envie como parâmetro, assim esse dado irá ser enviado a próxima função e vc poderá o manipular.

      }
    })(file);

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  async myFunction(document) {
    console.log(document.description);
    //a descrição pega pelo onload continua existindo c:
    //o resto do seu código
  }
```